# Get Current Culture and Language from current country where you are

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking a way to get the language and culture from the current geo location of user, for example if user is from Germany I want code to get that location of the user and change the language automatically. The reason I'm asking is that in my current country there is no culture (by default: English).

I tried this code:

```
var ri = new RegionInfo(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID);
string val = ri.ISOCurrencySymbol;
string[] cul1 = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages;
string name = RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.GeoId.ToString();
```

all these examples get `en-us`, which is incorrect. Is there a way that an ASP.NET application can know the exact country of a user ?

Comment: for example Kosovo, also Kosovo has no postal code and nothing

Comment: It's bad idea. I travel in Germany and do not speak German...

Answer (score 4):

In general, no.

More importantly, in principle, don't. Leave the user to choose their language the way they want - as a default. This happens automatically on ASP.NET (unless you're doing some fishy stuff), and works based on the user language specified in the browser (you likely have an english OS and/or you've set your language as english in browser settings). Always allow the user to override that language as well.

To test how this works, just go to your browser settings and change the language to something else. If your ASP.NET application is properly setup, it should be showing a different language/culture in `CurrentCulture`. And even if it's not, `Request.UserLanguages` *will* have the setting from your browser.